# Bundler trying to install development gems in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

When I try to deploy my Rails 5 application using Capistrano 3, it tries to install development gems even in staging. This is completely new behaviour and I have no idea where it's coming from (came in the middle of a bunch of commits to a controller, the deploy scripts or Gemfile weren't touched at all).

The relevant lines of the `capistrano.log` are:

```
bash: line 1: 13108 Killed /path/to/my/app/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh 2.4.0 bundle install --path /path/to/my/app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
bundle stderr: Nothing written
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details.
```

My capistrano.log can be found at [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mindseyeblind/914249e6de9e543866f24e956005934f/raw/0caff3e5fbbf11724bd43ea4e5700e6bbf391090/capistrano.log), but the gist of it is that it checks the bundle, which fails because the `group :development` gems aren't installed (obviously), and then tries to bundle install, which won't happen because they're in the development group. It's a weird, cyclical problem.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No dice, unfortunately. Ended up having to nuke the server and re-deploy from scratch. Not fun.

Comment: I ended up blowing mine away. wasn't using cap, but similar issue on an Ubuntu docker.

Comment: Perhaps a manual edit in `.bundle/config` would have helped?